# SQL - How to get certain characters from a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as:

```
id: Int,
URL: string,
//other fields
```

The URL field contains values like ["nytimes.com/live/", "prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/", "stackoverflow.com/questions",...]

How do I query to only get the domains of URLs ["nytimes.com", "prisma.io", "stackoverflow.com"...]

Right now I am doing it by fetching all the records and capturing the domain in server. I was wondering if there is a way to do this in SQL directly?

Comment: Show us your attempt and we can help you.

Comment: Right now I am doing it by fetching all the records and capturing the domain in server. I was wondering if there is a way to do this in SQL directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(URL, '/', 1) FROM table ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server,

- `CHARINDEX` returns the position of a given character.
- `SUBSTRING` returns the substring from the start of the string until the given index

Hence, combining `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` function, we can get the domain name.

Eg, if the domain name is `google.com`, the following query will return 'google'

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(URL, 1, CHARINDEX('.',URL)) FROM table_name
```

The solution for `mysql` database given by @ricardo-francois works just as intended.

```sql
CREATE  TABLE domains (id int auto_increment primary key, url varchar(100) not null);
INSERT INTO domains(url) values('nytimes.com/live/'),('google.com/crawl');

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(URL, "/",1) FROM table_name;
```

The last parameter `1` in the `SUBSTRING` function indicates the number of occurrences of the delimiter. Here, it will return all the texts until the first delimiter (which is "/")

Output :

```
nytimes.com
google.com
```

Comment: I think the database is `mysql` based on the tags